# How does the SQL Server engine load data in memory based on Clustered Index?

Tags: sql-server, tree, indexing

We all know that the Clustered index is struct the row data with B tree.
The root node and internal nodes store the cluster key and data address that reference to other columns.(call it key nodes)

The leaf nodes are store the datas.(call it data nodes)
Now my question comes, 
What's the progress of the DB load data?
Does is load the key nodes first. And engine match the parameters to the key value. So if we find the key node. we use the data address to load datas from physical disks immediately?

Or we load the entire tree first? I guess it may cause a bad performance.

Thank you for you advice!

Comment: This is not a question on how to resolve a problem, but a "request for comments" on SQL Server guts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what operation does SQL Server do with your clustered index.

On an `Index Seek`, it traverses the B-Tree from the root node to the node containing the key being searched, and then to the leaf node (if required).

On an `Index Scan`, it traverses leaf nodes horizontally (each leaf node contains pointers to the next and previous leaf node).

Either way it first tries to find each page in the buffer pool (this is called `logical read`) and, failing that, retrieves it from the disk (this is called `physical read`).

If you enable IO statistics by issuing

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

prior to running your query, you will see exactly how many logical and physical reads from each table your query does.